# Is it considered bad practice to have a module and function name be the same?

Tags: python

For example, here is a simplistic version.

```
from app import VERSION

def app():
    print(VERSION)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app()
```

Is this considered bad practice? I've looked at Python's [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide and can't find much with regards to this specific situation.

Comment: What is "bad practice"? Something that doesn't work, something that will work but has potential side effects, something that could lead to misunderstandings or is not very well readable, …? I think the better question is: `Is it considered *good* practice …`. That's a developer should go for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `from app import VERSION` and not `import app`, there will be no conflict of names between the module and the function, therefore it's OK to do that.

Comment: correct answer. Indeed, it coud've clashed but didn't thanks to the import of VERSION and not app. I would advise not to use the same names, to avoid such risk though.

Answer (score 3):

<s>No, that is not bad practice. Doing that is perfectly fine, for example if you look at one of python's builtins, [pprint.pprint()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint):</s>

> **pprint.pprint(object, stream=None, indent=1, width=80, depth=None)**
>
> Prints the formatted representation of object on stream, followed by a newline. If stream is None, sys.stdout is used. This may be used in the interactive interpreter instead of a print statement for inspecting values. indent, width and depth will be passed to the PrettyPrinter constructor as formatting parameters.

If the python dev's do it, surely it's ok if you do it too. Just be sure to avoid name clashing. But in general you shouldn't experience problems with that in these scenarios.

As hinted by SuperbiasedMan, there are many other builtins that do this, e.g. [`time.time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) and [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime).

---

As correctly pointed out by Apero, I slightly misunderstood your situation.

As a fix, I will emphasize what I said above already: *Just be sure to avoid name clashing*.

Because you did `from app import VERSION`, the `from app` doesn't clash with your `def app` function, making it so this piece of code will work fine.

My opinion however is that **this is bad practice**, because if you for some reason don't always do specific imports, but also use `import app`, then it will clash and your code could do unexpected things.

Comment: this wasn't the OP's question, even though the title can misguide us. In his case, the module is app, and he has an app function in this script which "could" conflict, if he was doing import app. But in his case, he isn't import app but VERSION from app, so it's fine.

Comment: @Apero thanks, that was my bad for misunderstanding.

Comment: `If the python dev's do it, surely it's ok if you do it too.` Maybe it's ok. Maybe not. Maybe a better question is: is it *good* practice instead of *bad* practice? But both questions could lead to very subjective opinions. I would recommend to stick to as much clean code as you can get from yourself. There are books about writing clean code.

Comment: @colidyre that makes sense. But I also believe that the language developers should (and do) set examples for the users. Anyway that part is striked out now